# Case statement in SQL Query using join

Tags: sql-server, left-join, case

I have two tables. Table 1: Operators

```
operator    price     effective_date
Operator1   2.2500    2019-04-03 00:00:00.000
Operator1   1.0000    2019-04-04 11:33:36.483
```

Second Table: Call

```
calls    duration     operator     setup_date
call 1   151          operator1    2019-04-01 00:00:00.000
call 2   173          operator1    2019-04-02 00:00:00.000
call 3    5           operator1    2019-04-05 00:00:00.000
call 4   38           operator1    2019-04-05 00:00:00.000
```

I want to check price according to operator effective date, for example call 1 and call 2 price should be 2.2500 and call 3 and call 4 price should be 1.000.

I used case statement but I am getting all records which is not correct. Can someone help me out here.

Adding my attempt for sql query

```
select calls.*, 
    case when setup_date <= Operators.effective_date
    then Operators.price 
    end as price
from calls
left join Operators on Operators.operator = calls.operator
```

Comment: Added my sql query attempt

Comment: If Tims answer is not what you are looking for, then please show us your expected results.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to pair up each record in the `Call` table with the closest record in the `Operator` table, corresponding to the same operator, with the closest matching time being either earlier or later.  One approach here would be to use a correlated subquery to search `Call` for this matching record.

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT TOP 1 o.price
     FROM Operators o
     WHERE o.operator = c.operator
     ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, c.setup_date, o.effective_date))) AS price
FROM Call c
ORDER BY
    operator,
    setup_date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Can we use here case expression also ?

Comment: select calls.*, 
    case when  setup_date <= Operators.effective_date then Operators.price 
    end
    as price  from calls
    left join Operators on Operators.operator= calls.operator

Comment: I was trying above query but end out getting all records

Comment: @PankashMann Your current approach is very far from a working solution, and you should probably abandon it.  Yes, the above query gets all records, but then again this is what you asked for, no?  You want to get a price for each call, isn't that right?